# Is terminal object the kernel of identity morphism?

Tags: category-theory, morphism

Let's say that there is a category $\mathbf{C}$ with $A$ being an object of that category and a zero object exists in that category. If we have an identity morphism ${id}_A: A\to A$, is the kernel of this morphism a terminal object of the category? My reasoning for this stems from the fact that the universal property of kernel requires a unique morphism going into $\ker(id)$, hence the terminal object.

Comment: Doesn't talking about kernels in a category presuppose having a zero object in that category?

Comment: Ah, yes it does. Edited the question now. Does that mean the kernel of the mapping should be the zero object (zero object being one of the terminal object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments by @Geoffrey Trang, the same argument applies to monomorphisms and dually to epimorphisms.

In fact, you can show that any isomorphism $f : A \longrightarrow B$ satisfies $ker(f) = 0$. Indeed, let $g: C \longrightarrow A$ such that $f \circ g = 0$. We want to show that $g$ factors through $0$. Well since $f$ is an isomorphism, $g = 0$. Hence, $g$ factors as $C \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow A$ and we have shown that $0$ satisfies the universal propertt of the kernel. Dually, the cokernel of an isomorphism is $0$.

Comment: Even more generally, monomorphisms and epimorphisms have zero kernel and cokernel respectively. The converse is true in preadditive categories ($\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched categories), but not in general.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit to mention this.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the fact that if a zero object exists in a category, than it should be isomorphic to the terminal object. Everything makes sense now.